# Как создать форму внутри панели другой формы? C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

нужна помощь!
У меня есть главная форма со слайд-меню по левому краю. В форме есть пустая панель, при клике на кнопки в меню, открывается форма внутри этой панели, соответствующая выбранной кнопке в меню. Так вот, внутри открывшейся формы есть так же buttons, при нажатии мне надо, чтобы снова открывалась ещё одна третья форма, внутри этой области, поверх предыдущих, соответствующая выбранной кнопке в форме.
Уже много чего мной было испробовано, но ничего не получается, либо пропадает выбранная кнопка, либо ничего не происходит. На форуме не могу найти нужную информацию - все попытки приводят к провалу.
Это вообще можно как-то реализовать?
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Используйте `UserControl`

Answer (score 0):

Постараюсь объяснить вкратце логику работы программы и вы сами найдете ошибку:

1. Слайд-меню и ее кнопки, главная форма и панель, внутри которой открываются новые формы, вызванные кнопками из слайд-меню, определенны в главном классе программы (быстрее всего что-то типа Form1);
2. Новые формы (класс Form2) являются уже другим классом и элементарно не видят область определения нужной нам панели, что бы внутри нее открыть уже третью форму (класс Form3).

Решений данного сценария (если я правильно угадал структуру вашего проекта) может быть масса. Предложу вам для начала такой путь:

Написать хендлер в Form1, который будет отслеживать нажатия кнопок на Form2 и при положительном результате создавать Form3 внутри той же панели, где и лежит Form2 уже. Найти примеры написания хендлеров (запрос будет "из Form1 отследить нажатие кнопки на Form2") будет уже не проблемой, но написать код не могу пока что, нет возможности.

С уважением и удачи.